# Best way to let others put a file in my desktop via Internet

Tags: file-sharing

My friend who is in charge of a printing store wants others to be able to send files to him. Normally we email pdf files to his email account. The problem with this is he need to manually download the attachments and print it.

What he wants is something similar to dropbox which let anybody to share/Send a file with him and the file will automatically be downloaded to a folder in his desktop. Does anybody know about any application which let him do this.

Comment: Linux or Windows? Cant he use a [smb share](http://www.samba.org/cifs/docs/what-is-smb.html)?

Comment: A VPN works for things like this. Actually, I just finished building an FTP client for someone which allowed customers to transfer files via FTP and he would receive an email when there was a new file. If this person has a company, you probably can create this functionality on the site (I know not exactly what you want, but safer than allowing any one drop any type of file on to his PC).

Comment: Windows Desktop. 24x7 Internet connectivity necessary in this machine so I don't think VPN is the solution. Also people need to be able to share over internet hence I don't think Samba will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service called ['DropItToMe'](http://www.dropitto.me/). It works by gaining access to your dropbox account.

The service homepage reads,

"Ever wish you could easily receive big files from anyone? Now you can! 
Together with Dropbox you can setup an unique upload address with password protection. "

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer comes with a integrated VPN function and a filesharing function. And if you don't like TV you can try https://join.me/.

Comment: Im sorry, i did not mean meebo (lol it was an IM Service) i mean join.me